# Memory allocation and structuring

Tags: memory-management, memory-address

How can we use a contiguous block of memory in such a way that some part of it links with the remaining part? For example if I allocate a contiguous block of bytes using malloc, and now I want to structure it in such a way that the initial part of the block will be structured as pointers which points to remaining part. That means the pointers and the pointing objects should be contiguous...??

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't make much sense to me.  Let's assume you wanted nItems of the size sizeBytes (meaning they are all the same size), you would not need to store the pointers, because you can compute the offsets to the allocated memory whenever you needed it.  So you are probably missing some criteria in your question.  Here is how you'd do that:

```
void *block = malloc(nItems * sizeBytes);
```

Then to reach into the `n-th`object, you'd simply do:

```
void *myMemory = block + n * sizeBytes;
```

You'd want to possibly do some bounds checking there...

But that's too easy, so I'm guessing you really have structures of different sizes that you want to allocate in a single malloc and get access to.  So it's not just a question of figuring out what the address of a "sub block of memory" is, but you'd want to know how to cast it so that you can later make sense of the object (assuming it's a C structure).  So I guess I'd have to say I remain confused by the question overall.

You'll probably want / need something like the pointer, the size, and the type of structure each "sub block" of memory is supposed to be.  This would then indicate what your header information should probably look like.  Roughly, you'd want to compute the storage required for your 'meta data' and then the 'payload data', and malloc those things together.

But it's not a trivial thing to implement, because you have to figure out how you tell your function that allocates / initializes the memory block what the mix of objects is going to be (and the sequence of the layout of each sub-object).

I'm afraid this question is woefully underspecified.

Comment: okay yes my ques is woefully under specified.!! here's is another analogy...if i allocate a typical 2D array using malloc() i get non continuous blocks in some blocks there are pointers to data in other there are data...i want to allocate all of them (by all of them i mean both pointers and data) to be continuous in memory..how do i do that???

Comment: If you want a 2D array of one type of object, you can do it like this:

Answer (score 0):

If you want a 2D array of one type of object, you can do it like this:

```
int entries = xSize * ySize;            // create a 2D array of xSize by ySize dimensions
size_t buffSize = entries * objectSize; // objectSize is number of bytes for your object
void *block = malloc(buffSize);
```

Now to access any entry in your 2D array:

```
void *thingie = block + y * xSize + x;
```

Now thingie points to block that corresponds to x, y.  If you wanted to, you can also change the layout of your memory object.  Above I did row-major.  You could do:

```
void *thing = block + x * ySize + y;
```

That would be column major.  The above can extend to n-dimensions:

```
int entries = xSize * ySize * zSize;    // create a 3D array of xSize, ySize, zSize dimensions
size_t buffSize = entries * objectSize; // objectSize is number of bytes for your object
void *block = malloc(buffSize);
```

And then:

```
void *thingie = block + z * ySize * xSize + y * xSize + x;
```

to get to your record in 3D cube.  You can take this to any dimension that you want, of course, you'll blow up your memory sooner than later if you're dealing with large objects in large dimensional spaces.